# Migrate Existing GWT Project to GWT Mobile Application and PhoneGap

Tags: gwt, mobile

I have an existing gwt project. I want to run it on various mobile platform. So I choose GWT Mobile and PhoneGap would be the ideal to start with. But the project is quite big, code-wise. Is there some tool available to migrate the code to new gwt-mobile(m-gwt) and gwt-phonegap? Or I have to write the code from scratch?

Regards,
Sandip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there are no tools to migrate the code from gwt to mgwt. The code changes should be some 20 % percentage of your project, if you followed MVP pattern suggested by GWT. If you would have followed MVP, then you can reuse all the layers except View layer and in any case I don't think you can just replace GWT components with mgwt components. As the mobiles have a different form factor and usage patterns, you will need to design your views suited to mobile. Just scaling down the website to mobile form factor will not provide a good user experience. So the page designs needs to be changed and you will need to code for that using mgwt and where ever you want to access the native layers of the mobile, you can use gwt phonegap.

Comment: Yes, you will have to write the views for mobiles.

Comment: Thanks. I understand, backend code will remain same, only front end need to rewritten.